# Rendering wrong Shape in libgdx? (Circle appearing as a diamond)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, shapes, geometry

Im triying to draw some circles, but for some reason its drawing diamonds.

A picture of whats going on:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcR3k.png)

The part of the code where im drawing the circles:

```
ymove = this.yO + espacioPerCasilla/2;
    for (int i=0; i< dimension; i++) {
        xmove = this.xO + espacioPerCasilla/2;
        for (int j=0; j< dimension ; j++) {
            shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(MyGdxGame.camera.combined);
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            shapeRenderer.circle(xmove,ymove,Circulo.calcularRadio(espacioPerCasilla));
            shapeRenderer.end();

            xmove = xmove + espacioPerCasilla;
        }
        ymove = ymove + espacioPerCasilla;
    }
```

Before printing the circles i drew the grid using lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that you're drawing too small.
Raise your dimensions to be on the double digits at least.

Try this `circle(float x, float y, float radius, int segments)`
Segments beeing the number of vertex to be drawn, make it 10, and see how it changes the shape of your circle.
Then raise it until it's acceptable.

Comment: I also had to fix my Ortographic camera ratios, because it was drawing elipses, but now that i fixed that its working nicely :)